# How to aggregate data by each day, week, month wise in corresponding week, month, year respectively in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my project I have a wastes collection and it is as follows

```
wastes:[
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-01-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-01-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-02-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-02-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-03-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-03-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        ........................................................
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-12-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
        {weight: 100, date: ISODate("2016-12-01T10:20:41.417Z")}
       ]
```

I want aggregate the waste on each month wise in current year like

```
results: [
          <month1>:{weight: 200},
          <month2>:{weight: 200},
          ......................
          <month12>:{weight: 200} 
]
```

And also week wise in current month and day wise in current week as follows

```
results:[
        <week1>:{weight: 100},
        .....................
        <week4>:{weight: 100}
        ]

results: [
          <day1>:{weight: 100},
          ....................
          <day7>:{weight: 100}
         ]
```

Note: week wise and day wise aggregated values are just a dummy values I need that kind of output.

Comment: You just [broke the rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NylmdC_uEM) It's one question per post so I suggest you split you ask different questions.

Comment: I am Sorry, new to rules ,  Instead splitting the question I can edit right?

Answer (score 6):

For all date time connected with query you need to $project it values from date field - [manual here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/month/)

Aggregation framework come with help in this case - please see basic query below, which have daily and weekly weight aggregate, so you can transform this query for other time periods or use one query per period:

```
db.timing.aggregate([{
        $project : {
            year : {
                $year : "$date"
            },
            month : {
                $month : "$date"
            },
            week : {
                $week : "$date"
            },
            day : {
                $dayOfWeek : "$date"
            },
            _id : 1,
            weight : 1
        }
    }, {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                year : "$year",
                month : "$month",
                week : "$week",
                day : "$day"
            },
            totalWeightDaily : {
                $sum : "$weight"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {

            _id : {
                year : "$_id.year",
                month : "$_id.month",
                week : "$_id.week"
            },
            totalWeightWeekly : {
                $sum : "$totalWeightDaily"
            },
            totalWeightDay : {
                $push : {
                    totalWeightDay : "$totalWeightDaily",
                    dayOfWeek : "$_id.day"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $match : {
            "_id.month" : 3
        }
    }
])
```

Example results for month 3 for my dummy data are below:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 10
    },
    "totalWeightWeekly" : 600,
    "totalWeightDay" : [ 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 400,
            "dayOfWeek" : 6
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 9
    },
    "totalWeightWeekly" : 1000,
    "totalWeightDay" : [ 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 600,
            "dayOfWeek" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 7
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 12
    },
    "totalWeightWeekly" : 400,
    "totalWeightDay" : [ 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 2
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 3,
        "week" : 13
    },
    "totalWeightWeekly" : 200,
    "totalWeightDay" : [ 
        {
            "totalWeightDay" : 200,
            "dayOfWeek" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

and to form shape as needed you could use $project phase

```
   {$project:{
                _id:0,
                "year" : "$_id.year", //this could be ommited but use $match to avoid sum of other years
                "month" : "$_id.month",  //this could be ommited but use $match to avoid sum of other months
                "week" :"$_id.week",                
                totalWeightWeekly:1

                }}
```

> output

```
{
    "totalWeightWeekly" : 600,
    "year" : 2016,
    "month" : 3,
    "week" : 10
}
```

Any comments welcome!