# NodeJS - Building date-related Mongoose Queries via URL patterns

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a node and mongo / mongoose application that allows me to import and then 'query' bank statements via URL patterns.

My Statement model looks like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var statementSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  method: { type: String },
  amount: { type: Number, required: true },
  category: { type: String, default: 'Not Set' },
  importDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true }
});

statementSchema.index({ "date":1, "name":1, "amount":1 }, { unique: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Statement', statementSchema);
```

and when I run a mongo query like `db.statements.find({ "name": "RINGGO" })`

I get a number of documents returned that look like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5907a2850780a44f671707f5"), 
  "amount" : -6.3, 
  "name" : "RINGGO", 
  "method" : "VIS", 
  "date" : ISODate("2017-03-23T00:00:00Z"), 
  "importDate" : ISODate("2017-05-01T21:03:01.770Z"),
   "category" : "Not Set", 
   "__v" : 0 
 }
```

I want to build the application so that:

- `domain.com/:vendor` returns all transactions at that vendor and the total spend
- `domain.com/:vendor/2017` returns all transactions at that vendor in 2017 and the total 2017 spend
- `domain.com/:vendor/2017/January` returns all transactions at that vendor in January 2017 and the total Jan 2017 spend
- `domain.com/:vendor/2017/January/wk01` returns all transactions at that vendor in wk 01 of January 2017 and the total wk 01 Jan 2017 spend

Currently I have a route (which passes data to Handlebars) that gets all spend (but not the total)

```
router.get('/:vendor?', function (req, res, next) {

var vendorName = req.params.vendor;
Statement.find({ name: req.params.vendor }, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error no entries found');
    }
    res.render('vendor', {
        vendor: vendorName,
        shop: doc
    });
});
```

Any advice on how to build the necessary queries would be great.  I've been reading (and practicing) with mongo aggregation but I'm not really near achieving what I would like.  I'm hoping to be able to use the structure to also build URL patterns domain.com/:category, domain.com/:category/2017 etc

I'm sorry, I've been ill (and still am) since I posted this question so I haven't had time to work on it much but I did get a little way based on the answer by @profesor79 to this question [How to aggregate data by each day, week, month wise in corresponding week, month, year respectively in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965707/how-to-aggregate-data-by-each-day-week-month-wise-in-corresponding-week-month)

I can execute the below in mongo shell

```
db.statements.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        year : {
            $year : "$date"
        },
        month : {
            $month : "$date"
        },
        week : {
            $week : "$date"
        },
        day : {
            $dayOfWeek : "$date"
        },
        _id : 1,
        name : 1,
        amount:1
    }
},
{
           $group : {
               _id : {
                   year : "$year",
                   month : "$month",
                   week : "$week",
                   day : "$day"
               },
               totalDailyAmount : {
                   $sum : "$amount"
               }
           }
       },
{
    $group : {

        _id : {
            year : "$_id.year",
            month : "$_id.month",
            week : "$_id.week"
        },
        totalWeeklyAmount : {
            $sum : "$totalDailyAmount"
        },
        totalDayAmount : {
            $push : {
                totalDayAmount : "$totalDailyAmount",
                dayOfWeek : "$_id.day"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match : {
        "_id.month" : 3,
        "_id.week" : 12
    }
}
]
)
```

and get back the result

```
{ "_id" : 
    { "year" : 2017, 
      "month" : 3, 
      "week" : 12 }, 
  "totalWeeklyAmount" : 2870.5099999999998, 
  "totalDayAmount" : 
        [ { "totalDayAmount" : -40, "dayOfWeek" : 1 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : 3366.35, "dayOfWeek" : 6 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : -185.27, "dayOfWeek" : 2 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : -29.8, "dayOfWeek" : 3 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : -58.5, "dayOfWeek" : 5 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : -132.27, "dayOfWeek" : 4 }, 
          { "totalDayAmount" : -50, "dayOfWeek" : 7 } 
        ] 
}
```

However 1) I can't figure out how to get the monthly and yearly totals of the spend (in the same way as is done for `totalDayAmount` in the second `group`ing)

2) I can't limit this to just transactions at a particular vendor.  I tried

```
{
    $match : {
        "_id.month" : 3,
        "_id.week" : 12,
        "name": "vendor-name"
    }
```

But the name isn't in the results.

I am thinking that the below may work

```
db.statements.aggregate([{
$match:{name:"RINGGO"}},{
$project:{
    year : {
        $year : "$date"
        },
    month : {
        $month : "$date"
        },
    week : {
        $week : "$date"
        },
    day : {
        $dayOfWeek : "$date"
        },
    _id : 1,
    name : 1,
    amount: 1
    }
},
{
    $group : {
    _id : {
       year : "$year",
       month : "$month",
       week : "$week",
       day : "$day"
           },
    totalDailyAmount : {
       $sum : "$amount"
           }
     }
    },
   {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            year : "$_id.year",
            month : "$_id.month",
            week : "$_id.week"
        },
        totalWeeklyAmount : {
            $sum : "$totalDailyAmount"
        },
        totalDayAmount : {
            $push : {
                totalDayAmount : "$totalDailyAmount",
                dayOfWeek : "$_id.day"
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

Comment: Posted an edit to describe some progress

Answer (score 0):

1. **URL pattern**

It's generally a good idea to use query parameters instead of params because it's easily extensible and order does not matter. In your case it should be:  `domain.com/?vendor=RINGGO&year=2017&month=January&week=1`. Later you can extend it with `&category=something`.

2. **Query**

As your query relies on date manipulation a lot, I'd suggest including [moment](https://momentjs.com/): `npm install moment --save` to make the tasks easier.

Assuming you follow the URL pattern above, the query should be:

```
var startTime;
var endTime;
var year = req.query.year;
var month = req.query.month? moment().month(req.query.month).format("M") : null; // January to 1
var week = parseInt(req.query.week);
var query = {
    name : req.query.vendor  // assuming only vendor is required
};

if(year && month && week){ //if all available
    //week-1 to week is the week of this month we need e.g. week 2 of January is 2017-01-08 & 2017-01-15 respectively
    startTime = new Date(moment([year, month -1]).startOf('month').add(week-1, 'weeks')); // month -1 because JS month starts from 0
    endTime = new Date(moment([year, month -1]).startOf('month').add(week, 'weeks'));
}
else if(year && month){ //if week unavailable
    //if January 2017 then 2016-12-31 & 2017-01-31 respectively
    startTime = new Date(moment([year, month -1]).endOf('month').subtract(1, "month"));
    endTime = new Date(moment([year, month -1]).endOf('month'));
}
else if(year){ // only year available
    //if 2017 then 2016-12-31 & 2017-12-31 respectively
    startTime = new Date(moment([year]).endOf('year').subtract(1, "year"));
    endTime = new Date(moment([year]).endOf('year'));
}

//add time to query if available
startTime && endTime ? query.date = {$gt: startTime, $lt: endTime}: null;

Statement.aggregate([
    {
        $match : query
    },
    {
         $group : {
           _id : "$name",  statements: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, //$$ROOT adds all the documents processed in grouping
           totalSpend: { $sum: "$amount" }
        }
    }
], function(err, statements){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log(statements)
    }
})
```

Simulating `domain.com/?vendor=RINGGO&year=2017&month=January&week=4`, here's what the test result looks like with my dummy db documents.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "RINGGO",
        "statements": [
            {
                "_id": "5907a2850780a44f671707f1",
                "amount": 10,
                "name": "RINGGO",
                "method": "VIS",
                "date": "2017-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
                "importDate": "2017-01-01T21:03:01.770Z",
                "category": "Not Set",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5907a2850880a44f671707f1",
                "amount": 10,
                "name": "RINGGO",
                "method": "VIS",
                "date": "2017-01-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                "importDate": "2017-01-01T21:03:01.770Z",
                "category": "Not Set",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "totalSpend": 20
    }
]
```